# How to fit all genes (labels) in chromosome ideogram plot made by RCircos package?

Tags: r, circos

I am using Rcircos to make a chromosome ideogram plot for my gene list (n = 45). However, I am getting this error:

```
 Not all labels will be plotted.
 Type RCircos.Get.Gene.Name.Plot.Parameters()
 to see the number of labels for each chromosome.
```

I am using the below-given script and what to know is there any way to fit all my genes in the chromosome ideogram plot

```
 library(RCircos)
 data(UCSC.HG19.Human.CytoBandIdeogram)
 RCircos.Set.Core.Components(
 cyto.info=UCSC.HG19.Human.CytoBandIdeogram, 
 chr.exclude = NULL, 
 tracks.inside = 10, tracks.outside = 0) 
 
 #Making a plot with RCircos
 out.file <- "RCircos_IF.pdf";
 pdf(file=out.file, height=8, width=8, compress=TRUE);
 RCircos.Set.Plot.Area();
 par(mai=c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25));
 plot.new();
 plot.window(c(-2.5,2.5), c(-2.5, 2.5));

 # plot chromosome ideogram
 RCircos.Set.Plot.Area();
 RCircos.Chromosome.Ideogram.Plot() 
 gene.lable.data = read.table ("IF.txt", sep="\t", header=T, row.names = 1) # IF.txt is my input file
 RCircos.Gene.Connector.Plot(gene.lable.data, track.num = 1, side = "in");
 track.num <- 2;
 RCircos.Gene.Name.Plot(gene.lable.data,name.col = 4, track.num)

 dev.off()
```

My input file looks like

```
    Chromosome  chromStart  chromEnd    Gene.name
    1   chr1    150363091   150476566   RPRD2
    2   chr1    150549369   150560937   ADAMTSL4
    3   chr1    91949371    92014426    BRDT
    4   chr1    31365625    31376850    FABP3
    5   chr1    150960583   150975004   CERS2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the maximum number of genes in `RCircos`, we could modified the `char.width` according to this [link](https://www.biostars.org/p/80175/#285205).
The actual value in a RCircos session could be modified with get and reset methods for plot parameters.

```r
params <- RCircos.Get.Plot.Parameters() #$char.width
params$char.width <- 100 #default 500
RCircos.Reset.Plot.Parameters(params)

#the maxLabels are updated accordingly
RCircos.Get.Gene.Name.Plot.Parameters()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that apart from params$char.width, we can also use

```
params$text.size
params$text.size <- 0.2 #default 0.4
params$base.per.unit < 50000 #imp #default value = 30000
```